# Union of contractions is a contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, contraction-operator

Can someone give me a proof of the following statement:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If  $w_{i} : D_{i} \rightarrow X$ , $D_{i} \subset X$, are contraction mappings with corresponding contractivity factors $s_{i}, i =1,...,n$,   then $W=
\cup_{i=1}^n w_{i}$ is a contraction mapping with contractivity factor  $s= \max\limits_{i=1,...,n}s_{i}$.
( $W(A) =   \cup_{i=1}^n w_{i}(A)$, $A \in X$)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint:* What metric do you put on the space on which your set-valued mappings operate on? That definition should help in verifying the statement.

Comment: I am not sure if this holds for arbitrary metric or Euclidean.  I found it on following link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2803681_Fractal_Compression

Answer (score 0):

*As stated*, the theorem is nonsensical. *If* $w_i = w_j$ in the intersection of the domains, the union of *functions* makes sense. But without this hypothesis, if the definition is
$$W(A) = \cup_{i=1}^n w_{i}(A)$$
for $A\subset X$ (**not** $A\in X$), the domain *isn't* $\bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i$.

EDIT: the original source (Fractals Everywhere) abominably quote in the linked paper:

[image: Fractals Everywhere]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just one question: is Lemma 5 on picture true only for Hausdorff metric? (meaning: if we put  metric defined on set X, it wouldn't be true)

Comment: @user121, the theorem is about the *space* $\cal H(X)\ne X$. The Hausdorff metric *depends* of the metric in $X$,